# Looping over variables

Tags: bash, for-loop

I have some questions regarding files. In my case I have some directory containing several sub-directories. I'd like to define that directory as some variable to easily access its subdirectories within my shell script. For example:

```
home= /home/gleb/Documents/script # here my script is located
tools= ${home}/tools # this is dir in my $home consisted of some sub-dir with scripts
files= ${home}/files # this is dir with some input files which i need to process
```

Then in the body of my script I have `for` loop to loop some files by the sequence commands (scripts) which are located in the sub-directories of $tools

```
for file in ${files}/*.pdb; do
  pushd ${tools}/subdir
  # make something
  popd
done
```

Unfortunately this quick access to sub-directories within the loop is not working so I have to define seperate paths to each subdir explicitly (without variables) that is not very comfortable or efficient.

Could you explain why this method does not works and how it could be fixed?

Comment: Note that when assigning value to variable then space is not allow before and after `=`. see your `home= ` and `tools= ` and `files= ` variables.

Comment: Run your script through [SpellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/)